# How to do branch and merge operation in VSS?

Tags: version-control

Anybody describe me with the example and step by step operation about how to branch a code and then after branching how to merge back the changes in main code.

Thanks & Regards,
Hussain

Comment: AKAIK, you can only merge one file at a time in VSS... It's almost not worth the hassle.

Comment: See also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169/whats-the-right-way-to-branch-with-visual-source-safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no branching is VSS. All work is done on the main trunk. Use a better version control tool if you can.

What you could do, if you felt so inclined, is:

*Branching*

- Get the latest version of the code of the project you want to branch
- Create a new VSS project
- Copy your code into the working folder of the new project (this is your new "branch")
- Make your changes
- Commit them into the new project

*Merging*

- Take the code of your branch and copy it into the folder holding the latest version of the original project.
- Hope no one else had the original project checked out
- Commit the changes

I don't recommend this.

Answer (score 3):

To branch right click drag the project you want to branch to it's new location. A dialog will pop up, select the 'Share and Branch' option, another dialog will pop up, check Recursive (assuming you have some sub folders) then click OK and wait.

Reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xbxd2h7b(v=vs.80).aspx

Merging (which I've never had to do) reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181073(v=vs.80).aspx