# How to share projects of source safe branches?

Tags: .net, version-control, visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions, visual-sourcesafe-2005

coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656396/how-to-clone-a-complete-net-solution) i created a branch in visual source safe 2005 to get a copy of my solution which consists of 3 projects. This is working.

But i need to share two of the projects(a class library and the DAL) between the branch and the "main-project". So one project should be separate and two other should be shared. How to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VSS explorer, if you drag & drop your source folder to the desired target folder using the **right** mouse button, when you release the button you will get a context menu, the option you want is to `Share and Branch`.

Comment: I've first recognized that i can do that also with drag&drop. I think now i've understood the diference between branch and share. Thanks.